# Apache Ignite for .Net: is there any limitation on the use of async methods with Service Grid?

Tags: ignite

Can I use async methods in my services hosted in Apache Ignite for .Net 2.7.1? Are there any limitations or gotchas related to that? Just asking because there is no mention of async methods in the discussion about Service Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use async methods inside Ignite Service calls.

One thing to keep in mind is Services thread pool size. All Service calls are executed on a [separate thread pool](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thread-pools#section-services-pool), which has a size of `max(8, total number of cores)` by default.

You may want to increase that size by changing `IgniteConfiguration.ServiceThreadPoolSize` property.